# How did 中風 become “suffering a stroke”?

Tags: etymology

I have learned the Chinese names of some common ailments and they are surprisingly very descriptive and intuitive once you know the meanings of the individual characters.

For example: 糖尿病，高血壓，心律失常.

But what happened to 中風, and how did this become “suffering a stroke”?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you're only asking about 中風, right?  (Please continue [edit]ing if I've misunderstood something.)

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Yes, you are right. I am only asking about 中風. Though you are welcome to add other ailments/conditions that are not defined by their individual characters like 中風.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [中風](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E9%A2%A8_(%E4%B8%AD%E9%86%AB))，中醫學術語，中醫認為這是外感風邪侵犯人體之後所造成的病證。

> 因為「**風者，擅行而數變**」，有許多症狀都被歸類在中風之下，但最主要的，有兩個意義，一是指因腦血管阻塞、出血而造成的病變，亦即現代醫學所說的**中風**

> '中風' (suffer a sickness caused by 'something' in the wind)-- a term in Traditional Chinese medicine. Traditional Chinese medicine believed that it was a disease syndrome caused by external wind pathogens invading the human body.

> Because "**wind is invisible, move fast, and unpredictable**", many symptoms are classified under '中風', but the most important one has two meanings. One refers to the pathological changes caused by cerebrovascular obstruction and bleeding, that is, **Stroke** in modern medicine

In the olden time, when someone fell ill suddenly without any apparent cause, people had to blam something invisible. The obvious choices were wind and evil spirit. A stroke had to be caused by something in the wind they thought.

*For the same logic, when someone suffered a mental breakdown (發瘋 - get crazy), people might suspect the patient had 揰邪 (ran into an evil spirit)*

Comment: Add a bit for "中 zhòng", got/suffered something, like 中奖, 中暑, 中彩.